# Ho to Create text View with skew pattern with out adding \t of \n?

Tags: android

I want to create text view different margin starts for different lines(Line skew pattern) with out\t of \n. for example:

[image: please click here .]

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use either `padding` or `margin` and maybe look at separating the texts into separate `Textviews` to achieve this...

**Example:**

```
  <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" <!--either margin or padding -->
            android:text="Stackoverflow..." />
```

I've seen other answers regarding the use of `Webviews`and using text set to `HTML` to display in the `Webview`.

Could work potentially.